# "Cannot open shared object file" Error even though ldconfig is showning entry

Tags: ubuntu, libraries

I'm trying to run a older SIMetrix Version on Ubuntu 15.04 64bit (if there is a newer version of SIMetrix around tell me!).

When I do it I get following error:

`user@user-Ubuntu-Laptop:/opt/simetrix_intro_53/bin$ ./SIMetrix 
./SIMetrix: error while loading shared libraries: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

But when I run `sudo ldconfig -v | grep Xext` the output is `libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0`.

So why is the file not found? Running SIMetrix with sudo doesn't help.

---

`user@user-Ubuntu-Laptop:/opt/simetrix_intro_53/bin$ sudo linux32 --3gb ./SIMetrix
./SIMetrix: error while loading shared libraries: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

---

`$ file ./SIMetrix
./SIMetrix: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped`

---

`$ uname -a
Linux user-Ubuntu-Laptop 3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:09:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

---

`$ ldd ./SIMetrix
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf777f000)
    libSupportDll.so => /opt/lib/simetrix/5.3/libSupportDll.so (0xf7704000)
    libqt-mt.so.3 => /opt/lib/simetrix/5.3/libqt-mt.so.3 (0xf6ed9000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf6ec3000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf6d78000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf6d5b000)
    libstdc++.so.5 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf6d0e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6cf0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf6b35000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf6b30000)
    libstdc++.so.5 => not found
    libGL.so.1 => not found
    libXmu.so.6 => not found
    libSM.so.6 => not found
    libICE.so.6 => not found
    libstdc++.so.5 => not found
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6b0d000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7780000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6b08000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf6b01000)`

Comment: I think you install 32bit program on 64 or reverse....

Comment: You can run via `linux32` on 64 bit machine or `linux64` on 32 bit machine.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I have a 64bit system and the binary is made for 32bit. But the solution you suggested doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Install the corresponding 32 bit library, perhaps? I.e. you probably have libxext6:amd64, but try installing libxext6:i386 as well. Paste the output of `file ./SIMetrix `, `uname -a`, `ldd  ./SIMetrix` into your question.

Comment: Hey  Faheem Mitha, your suggestion did it! I installed libxext6:i386 with apt-get. Now libstdc++.so.5 is missing. Any way to install all dependencies at once?

Comment: installing `libstdc++:i386` gives following error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6-4.4-dev:i386 : Depends: g++-4.4:i386 (= 4.4.7-8ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-dbg:i386 : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.4-dbg:i386 but 4.4.7-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.6-dev:i386 : Depends: g++-4.6:i386 (= 4.6.4-6ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dbg:i386 : Conflicts....`
This is not a lot of fun, though I think the question is anwered, thanks for your help everyone!